# Can't count the digits in the last word in the last line of text file in C

Tags: c, file, count, digits

I have to write the number of words containing more than 2 digits in it. Everything it's okay **until it comes to the last word in the last line** that cannot be count. I can't count the digits in the last word. Here is the code:

```
while(fgets(row,MAX,fp) != NULL)
{
    int flag = 0; 
    int digits = 0;
    int words = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(row); i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(row[i]))
        {
            if(!flag)
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
            if(isdigit(row[i]))
            {
                digits++;
            }
        }
        else if(flag)
        {
            flag = 0;
            if(digits > 2)
            {
                words++; //words containing more than 2 digits
            }
            digits = 0;
        }
        printf("%d\n%s",words,row);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the value you are giving in MAX ? I think, fscanf may be more convenient in this. You can read word by word using this.

Comment: How to read a word by word with fscanf inside a while(fgets(red,100,fp) loop?

Comment: I have given the fscanf example in below.

Comment: The final (no alpha) value is never reached because fgets() stops at the end of a line and inserts a '\0' where the end of line marker used to be.  Also strlen does not count the '\0' at the end of a string.  Therefore, the loop stops one char too soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no non-alphabetical character at the end of file, So the **ELSE block** does not runs , Place a non-alphabetical character at the end of the file, like a dot.

Answer (score 0):

In this condition-

```
    if(isalpha(row[i])) // I think yo should use "isalnum(row[i])"
    {
        if(!flag)
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
        if(isdigit(row[i]))
        {
            digits++;
        }
    }
```

Because if a character is not an alphabet(Consider it is digit), it wont enter inside it. Then how it will increment `digits`?. Use `isalnum(row[i])` instead of `isalpha(row[i])`.

Then i think the remaining code is working fine!

Try the following change-

```
    if(isalnum(row[i])) 
    {
        if(!flag)
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
        if(isdigit(row[i]))
        {
            digits++;
        }
    }
```

For your reference-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 100
int main()
{
        FILE *fp;
        char row[MAX];
        int i;
        fp=fopen("FileXYZ","r"); // where FileXYZ is the file name

        int words = 0;
        while(fgets(row,MAX,fp) != NULL)
        {
                int flag = 0 ;
                int digits = 0;
                for(i = 0; i < strlen(row); i++)
                {
                        if(isalnum(row[i]))
                        {
                                if(!flag)
                                {
                                        flag = 1;
                                }
                                if(isdigit(row[i]))
                                {
                                        digits++;
                                }
                        }
                        else if(flag)
                        {
                                flag = 0;
                                if(digits > 2)
                                {
                                        words++; //words containing more than 2 digits
                                        printf("%d\n%s",words,row);
                                }
                                digits = 0;
                        }
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

And file content is -

```
a3b4cd
ab4c4d5
abcd
2ab3cd
abcd
i6k7k8
h0g9j
ywer4t
```

Ouput-

```
root@sathish1:~/My Docs/Programs# ./a.out 
1
ab4c4d5 
2
i6k7k8
```

Comment: it is alnum i made mistake writing it here :)

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf` to read the file. Just an simple example is given below.

```
main ()
{
    char row [ 100];

    FILE *fp = fopen ("/vol/users/test/sample.txt", "r");

    while(fscanf(fp, "%s", row) ==1)
    {
       printf("%s\n",row);
    }

}
```